# Sonar Analysis using Jenkins can't find executable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

I'm trying to trigger a sonar analysis of an android application through Jenkins and the Sonar Runner plugin. I've added a "Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis" build step to my job that builds the code using Ant. When it gets to the Sonar Analysis step it fails and outputs the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SONAR ANALYSIS FAILED
------------------------------------------------------------------------
FATAL: Sonar runner executable was not found for Sonar Runner 2.2.2
Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure
```

The jenkins agent is a remote linux server where I have installed the sonar-runner in /opt/ and have updated appropriate SONAR_RUNNER_HOME and PATH variables.

Have I installed the runner correctly? I've looked at the documentation and other similar installation related questions but have not found what my problem could be.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to set the path of the runner correctly in Jenkins. It's the path without */bin in the end. That's a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

In the Manage Jenkins section, Configure... did you set the Sonar Runner Installations correctly? Check box Install automatically and install automatically the version from Codehaus.

Comment: Yes. I'm thinking I have to extract the sonar-runner-dist zip in the jenkins/tools/ directory?

Answer (score 1):

Install Sonar Runner in the same server where Jenkins has been installed.

Comment: Could you give more details? Jenkins version? Sonar Runner version? Sonar server version?